# Make Google my default contact type on T-Mobile my touch 4G

Tags: contacts, sync

New contacts sync to T-Mobile instead of Google unless I manually change the contact type EVERY time I add a contact to my phone.

I want the default to be Google not T-Mobile

Answer (score 1):

For my Verizon HTC Thunderbolt, I opened the People application (hopefully the same as Contacts), opened the menu, clicked View (an eye icon), then unselected everything but Google. After that, when I click to add a new contact, Google is automatically selected.